# Get active caret position like Apple Dictation

Tags: macos, cocoa, applescript

I want to create Mac application that displays like Apple Dictation. How can I get the active caret position to show my window there?

[image: Something like this]

Comment: Yuo have to open the application's dictionary and see if there is an entry for this. Most applications won't have it. BBEdit might be one of the apps that allow you to get the position of the caret. Probably, you need to rethink your strategy.